# Python Object Wrapper

Tags: python

I am trying to create a wrapper class that behaves almost like the wrapped object.  So far, I have come up with the following code:

```
import functools
import types

method_wrapper = type((None).__str__)

class Box:

    def __new__(cls, obj):
        attrs = {}
        attr_names = dir(obj)

        for attr_name in attr_names:
            attr = obj.__getattribute__(attr_name)

            if isinstance(attr, (types.MethodType, method_wrapper)):
                "Attr is a bound method, ignore self"
                @functools.wraps(attr)
                def wrapped_attr(self, *args, **kwargs):
                    return attr(*args, **kwargs)
                attrs[attr_name] = wrapped_attr

            elif isinstance(attr, types.FunctionType):
                "attr is a static method"
                attrs[attr_name] = staticmethod(attr)

            else:
                "attr is a property"
                attrs[attr_name] = attr

        cls = type(type(obj).__name__,
                   (cls, type(obj)),
                   attrs)

        return object.__new__(cls)
```

I tried testing it with:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    x=Box(object())
```

However it comes up with the following error message:

```
TypeError: __init__() should return None, not 'NotImplementedType'
```

`__init__` is being properly dispatched by `isinstance(attr, (types.MethodType, method_wrapper))`, and `wrapped_attr` seems to be executed.  Do you have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Out of curiosity, what are you trying to achieve with this code?

Comment: I found [this solution](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496741-object-proxying/) for my larger goal of writing a proxy class, however, I still would like to know why __init__ is returning NotImplemented.

Comment: @EdgarAroutiounian I am trying to add debug info to a LISP interpreter that I wrote.  Using a proxy object, which contains the debug info, would allow me to preserve the structure of my evaluator and parser, while changing the tokenizer and the error handler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
for ...:
    attr = ...
    ...
    def wrapped_attr(...):
        ..attr..
```

This doesn't work as expected, because `attr` is rebound to various values by the `for` loop.  All subfunctions will see the last value bound, not the value it had in that iteration of the loop.  In this case, the last value bound, in alphabetical order, is `__subclasshook__`, which tends to return NotImplemented when called with random arguments.

Comment: Thanks! Is the best workaround to generate a closure and pass in `attr`, As in `def closure(attr):def wrapped_attr(...):...`? That method just seems a bit messy.

Comment: @Joshua: Yes.  Blame Python's scoping rules, which are usually nice but have slightly unexpected effects like this one.